# Activity call StartActivityForResult

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is it possible to start an activity in **StartActivityForResult()** and save the state of this new activity when she run the result?

ex:
Activity A starts Activity B by StartForResult, when activity B do their jobs and return the appropriate values​​, I can save the state of the activity with B **OnSaveStanceState**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, actually `OnSaveInstanceState` won't even be called in this case.

[`OnSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) is called **iff** the activity is killed by OS because of things like low memory, orientation changes.

But since you start **B** by using `StartActivityForResult`, you can always manually save the state of **B** by calling `Intent.PutExtra` before it is finished. It is all up to you what kind of state in **B** you need to save. Then **A** will get the state and you can use it later.

Comment: Thanks, I decided differently, states put the screen in a static property of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible. The lifecycle of the activity stops when they are finished. OnSaveInstanceState won't be called when an activity quits. You could try to get the current state in your activity A and pass it on to the new Activity B so you can rebuild the old state.